# sql delete query with "%" operator in c#

Tags: c#, sql

i'm trying to delete a row giving a value of a column, but it only deletes when i give the full value (i.e name column = sam jack) then to delete it i have to input sam jack.
so i'm trying to use the % operator but don't know how to put it in the query.
here is my code :

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.workers WHERE Name like @name" + "%";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) also.

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.workers WHERE Name like @name";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name","%" + searchString + "%");
```

Or if you want to delete only starts with your string, don't use first `%` like;

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", searchString + "%");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either concatenate `%` and the parameter value in the host language, or you can do it in SQL:

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.workers WHERE Name like @name+'%'";
```

In SQL Server 2012 you can use `CONCAT` to be more explicit:

```
command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM dbo.workers WHERE Name like CONCAT(@name, '%')";
```